# paypal express checkout problem

Tags: paypal

Hi I am integrating paypal with my website. I want that user enter their all information on my site (creditcard information and personal information).

I have down loded paypalfunctions.php from paypal developer website.

My code is :-

```
if(isset($_POST['submitCard']))
{
 $firstName  =trim($_POST['firstName']);
 $lastName  =trim($_POST['lastName']);
 $street   =trim($_POST['street']);
 $city   =trim($_POST['city']);
 $state   =trim($_POST['state']);
 $zip   =trim($_POST['zip']);
 $countryCode =$_POST['country'];
 $currencyCode ='USD';
 $paymentType ='Sale';
 $paymentAmount =$_POST['productPrice'];
 $creditCardType =$_POST['cardType'];
 $creditCardNumber=$_POST['cardNo'];
 $expDate  ='122015';
 $cvv2   =$_POST['cvv'];
 $returnResult=DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,
        $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, 
        $countryCode, $currencyCode );
 echo '<pre>';
     print_r($returnResult);
```

DirectPayment method is in paypalFunctions.php and this is

```
function DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,
       $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, 
       $countryCode, $currencyCode )
 {
  //Construct the parameter string that describes DoDirectPayment
  $nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCode;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" . $creditCardType;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ACCT=" . $creditCardNumber;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&EXPDATE=" . $expDate;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CVV2=" . $cvv2;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&FIRSTNAME=" . $firstName;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LASTNAME=" . $lastName;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STREET=" . $street;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CITY=" . $city;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STATE=" . $state;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&COUNTRYCODE=" . $countryCode;
  $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  $resArray=hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

  return $resArray;
 }


 /**
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
   * @methodName is name of API  method.
   * @nvpStr is nvp string.
   * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
   '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
 function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
 {
  //declaring of global variables
  global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
  global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
  global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
  global $sBNCode;

  //setting the curl parameters.
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

  //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

     //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
    //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
  if($USE_PROXY)
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT); 

  //NVPRequest for submitting to server
  $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

  //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

  //getting response from server
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
  $nvpResArray=deformatNVP($response);
  $nvpReqArray=deformatNVP($nvpreq);
  $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

  if (curl_errno($ch)) 
  {
   // moving to display page to display curl errors
     $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
     $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

     //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
  } 
  else 
  {
    //closing the curl
     curl_close($ch);
  }

  return $nvpResArray;
 }


    }
    ?>
```

it gives error

```
         Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2010-12-21T06:06:54Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 1cafc53222e76
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 64
    [BUILD] => 1620725
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

i cant understand what is problem is going on.Please help.

Comment: Just a heads up : do you know that in order to accept credit card information on your own site, you need to be PCI compliant: http://selfservice.talisma.com/display/2n/index.aspx?c=58&cpc=MSdA03B2IfY15uvLEKtr40R5a5pV2lnCUb4i1Qj2q2g&cid=81&cat=&catURL=&r=0.420776844024658?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to need to worry about as well:

1. Login to the developer site:
   https://developer.paypal.com/
2. Go to Applications
3. On the left side, hit "Sandbox Accounts"

You should be able to create one of type BUSINESS right there with the "Create Account" button if there isn't one.

1. Click on the account, choose "Profile", make sure the account is the BUSINESS kind.
2. The API Credentials tab will the display the username/password/signature you want to use.

If you don't use the credentials of a sandbox account when using the sandbox url, you are likely to get this 10002 Security error not valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Have configure your API credentials correctly?
you can dump the hash_call out if needed.

If you are doing sandbox testing,
Make sure the endpoint of the call is: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
-- pointed to the 'SANDBOX'

Comment: and also you have to config   global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;